# How does Owncloud know if a new file is uploaded?

Tags: php, owncloud

I'm working on an Owncloud app, but I am wondering how Owncloud knows if a new file is uploaded.
Can someone point it out?

Comment: Your question is a little vague.  I'm sure there is a process that writes to the database once the file has been uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

You're not too clear on what exactly you want to achieve, but to me it sounds like you want your app to get notified whenever a new file is uploaded, is that right?

Then you should take a look at [filesystem hooks](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.0/developer_manual/app/hooks.html?highlight=hook#filesystem-root) - preCreate or postCreate is probably for you depending on when you want to react...